# Need to deserialize list within JSON data?

Tags: c#, json.net

I have the following returned JSON and I would like to pull out just the information in the `processResults`. I don't really care about the `requestId`.

```json
{
  "requestId": "884a118f-e599-43a7-9a0c-6ce5afbdb36b",
  "processResults": [{
    "code": "SYS_DESERIALIZATION_ERROR",
    "context": "punch.PunchId",
    "level": "ERROR",
    "message": "Could not find member 'PunchId'."
  }]
}
```

I created these two classes and then called `DeserializeObject()`. This pulls out the data, but I feel like there should be a way to get just the `processRequest` results into a list instead of having to create the extra `RequestResponse` class.

```
class RequestResponse
{
    public string requestId { get; set; } 
    public List<ProcessResults> processResults { get; set; } 
}

public class ProcessResults
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Level { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; } 
}
```

Then I used this code to try to deserialize. It works, but is there a better way to just pull the `ProcessResults` data into a list?

```
RequestResponse requestResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RequestResponse>(response.Content);
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem with your current solution? If you don't want `requestId` then just remove that property from the `RequestResponse` class

Comment: There is a way not to create wrapper class but I would say that it is not cleaner then with wrapper class. You can just omit all properties which you don't care about.

Comment: There isn't really anything wrong with way I did it and that works but just felt like it's an extra class that's not necessary but maybe this is best way to do it.

Comment: For any serialization library to be able to (de)serialize objects in a standard way, the structure of the input need to match the structure of the output. Since your JSON has a wrapping object, then your C# classes also need to. Otherwise you need to implement your own custom deserialization which I wouldn't recommend

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing inherently wrong with the approach you have right now, but if you are really against having a root class, you can get around it by using a [`JObject`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm) instead:

```
var jo = JObject.Parse(response.Content);
var processResults = jo["processResults"].ToObject<List<ProcessResults>>();
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/hW0Qsu